# Proper style to ignore a None value in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust and looking for good style options to handle following:

Let's say that `foo` returns `Option<i32>`. I'm calling `foo` in a loop and in the case that it returns `None` I simply want to move on. Right now I find myself doing something like:

```
for _whatever in something {
  let data = foo();
  if data.is_none() {
    continue;
  }
  let data = data.unwrap();
  // other stuff
}
```

Not bad, pretty readable, but I can't help but feeling like it could be more concise. This feels like a pretty common use case, and I was wondering what other options I might have to achieve something similar, and if there was an accepted best practice for dealing with `None` in this way.

I've tried using `match` statements and conditionals on `is_none`, finding the later slightly preferable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfect case for `let`-`else`:

```rust
for _whatever in something {
    data = foo();
    let Some(data) = data else { continue };
    // other stuff
}
```

Comment: `let Some(data) = foo() else { continue };` for minimal length

Answer (score 7):

`if let` could be helpful

```
for _whatever in something {
    if let Some(data) = foo() {
        // other stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could integrate it into the iterator and flatten it to remove `None` values.

```rs
for data in something.into_iter().flat_map(|_| foo()) {
  // other stuff
}
```

Comment: This is a great idea, however I would argue that you probably shouldn't mix iterator operations and for loops, and instead use `for_each`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to take advantage of the "functor" nature of `Option` and use the built in `inspect` function to get a reference to the data:

```rust
for _whatever in something {
  foo().inspect(|data| {
    // other stuff
  })
}
```

Note that you will only have a reference to the value. There are other helpers which would give you ownership. The [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.inspect) contains more details about your options.

The other answer with `if let` is more idiomatic in my opinion, but the functional programming alternative also exists.

### Edit

After looking at the documentation myself, I noticed that `inspect` is only available in the nightly build. You could use the `map` method instead with similar results, but note that `map` takes ownership of the underlying data.